# Can bacteria or other microorganisms be killed by applying pressure?

Tags: bacteriology, biophysics

Can you smash a bacteria (or any microorganism) and kill it?
Let's say there is millions of microorganisms on a table. When you put your finger on the table, will or can you kill at least some of them ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is just too silly.

Comment: Good physics oriented question. According to @JayCkat 's answer; the bacteria require 40 **k** psi; whereas human beings die after [43.5 to 58 psi](http://oureverydaylife.com/can-oceans-pressure-crush-you-42326.html) So the question could be improved as, "why bacteria would need so huge pressure to die whereas larger organism die at much less pressure".

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can kill bacteria using pressure. The devised used is called a French press

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/French_pressure_cell_press

http://www.glenmills.com/cell-disruption/high-pressure-homogenizer/french-press-gm/

However the pressure use is about 40k psi.... which is a lot higher pressure than anything a human body can generate.

Other methods to kill bacteria include, 
heat, gamma radiation, oxidative chemicals, antibiotics, dehydration, salt, oxygen exclusion, freezing.

However bacteria are a very diverse group, so it might take one or more methods in combination to kill all bacteria (and their spores) in a sample.

Comment: I'm probably being overly pedantic here, but a human can certainly easily generate 40,000 psi, if merely by standing on something pointy (a surface of up to a few sq mm, depending on your mass). Of course, clearly not as OP is suggesting by pushing your finger on a table without the aid of something like a pin.

Comment: Well if you get a 70kg person to stand and balance his complete weight on a pin (2 mm2),... then yes, 40k psi can be achieved by a human body. But if we start factoring aids, a human can do a lot of things.